# How to program to generate 3D Models?

Tags: web-applications, 3d, rich-internet-application

I'm a beginner in 3D Programming. I wanna build a web that provide users can create their own avatar (3D model).

For example, I have sample models of face, body, clothes, etc. and users can choose this sample model to create 3D avatar.

What platform or tools which I need to build this function?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to using 3D on the web, the most widely adopted method is using Flash. Alternatives include using a Java applet, or upcoming web technologies like the HTML5 canvas.